# Mui modal backdrop black color

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm currently using mui modal and it has a backdrop of solid black even though when I said I want the background transparent.
I did try to set it as color: transparent

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, just add this css change **'& .MuiBackdrop-root': { backgroundColor: 'transparent' }**

```
  <Modal
    open={open}
    sx={{ '& .MuiBackdrop-root': { backgroundColor: 'transparent' } }}
    onClose={handleClose}
    aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
    aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
  >
```

Here is a working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-npuups?file=demo.tsx